# Threads concurrency issue java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running two threaded classes and a third class (Execute)s them.

```
Class1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            Thread.sleep(random());
//random will ensure non-periodicity in generating strings
//Because of this, sometimes, many strings are generated simultaneously and other times, there is delay.
            Execute.q.add(generateRandomString());
        }
    }
}

Class2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            Thread.yield();
            if(!Execute.q.isEmpty){
                System.out.println(Execute.q.remove());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Execute{
    public static Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        (new Class1()).start();
        (new Class1()).start();
        (new Class2()).start();
        (new Class2()).start();
    }
}
```

The issues I'm facing are these:

1. Some of the generated strings are getting printed more than once, which means as soon as there is some string pushed into the `q`, more than one threads remove that element at the same time, and print.
2. Some of the generated strings are never printed.
3. Sometimes, the output gets delayed, ie. if 5 strings are generated by Class1, only 3 get printed. Now, again if it generates 3 more strings, the previous 2 (left) get printed.

How can I resolve these?

Comment: Synchronize the access to 'q'.

Comment: Use a proper data structure like a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Why don't you post real, compiling code? Now we wonder at each line if that's really what you're doig or not, given that half of the lines are invalid.

Comment: @JBNizet, the whole code is not possible to post. I assure you, this is all the relevant part.

Comment: I didn't ask for the whole actual code. I asked for real, compiling code. I.e. what you posted, but with all the syntax and compilation errors fixed.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it, but I think only Execute class is "lazily" written. @JBNizet

Comment: The compiler would disagree.

Comment: What...you want implementation of my `random()` function and `generateRandomString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use thread-safe `Queue` implementation from `java.util.concurrent` (e.g. `BlockingQueue`) or use `synchronized` keyword.

See as well https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` is not thread safe. You should use some kind of `BlockingQueue`:

```
    public static BlockingQueue<String> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Some of the generated strings are getting printed more than once, which means as soon as there is some string pushed into the q, more than one threads remove that element at the same time, and print.

This most likely is due to the access to `q` not being synchronized, i.e. two or more instance of `Class2` call `remove()` almost simultaneously messing with the `LinkedList` implementation which is also not threadsafe.

What you probably want is a `synchronized(Execute.q){ ... }` block inside the loops (excluding the sleep and yield calls).

> Some of the generated strings are never printed.

This might have the same reason as above since you're messing `LinkedList` when concurrently calling `remove()` etc.

> Sometimes, the output gets delayed, ie. if 5 strings are generated by Class1, only 3 get printed. Now, again if it generates 3 more strings, the previous 2 (left) get printed.

Threads are not guaranteed to run in any order so the producer can run 5 times and then the consumer is selected to run 3 times. Nothing unusual here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    `public static volatile Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();`
instead of
    `public static Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();`

It should help without synchronizing methods or using synchronized block.

Comment: Accessing a non-thread-safe LinkedList concurrently is still incorrect. Making it volatile won't fix the problem.